# contentEditable={"plaintext-only"} in a react component with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In a react component, I'm trying to incorporate a plain text only contenteditable div, but as we use typescript the contenteditable property can not be a string.
So in my .tsx-file when I enter this:

```
contentEditable={"plaintext-only"}
```

I get this error:

> Types of property 'contentEditable' are incompatible. Type
>   '"plaintext-only"' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.

How can I make it plain text only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the check the `type` of property `contentEditable`,it only accepts `boolean` or `undefined`.

Thats why you are getting the error, you are trying to pass the `string` value.

You can remove the issue, if you update the type of `contentEditable` to `string`
instead of `boolean`

Comment: Thanks Praveen! The type is from the official definition: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react, but you are right. I tried to add string as a type, and it worked. (I also created a pull request, so if they see it fit maybe they will add it to upcoming versions).

Comment: @burktelefon can you share how did you do that?